# Angular2 RxJS ForkJoin Alternative

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

When using forkJoin all items (in this case HTTP requests) are sent to the server instantaneously, then emitted as an array:

```
let observable_array = [observable1, observable2, ...];

Observable.forkJoin(observable_array).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('Res: ', res);
}, err => {
  console.log('Err: ', err);
});
```

This is a problem for me because I'm using a single-threaded server (NodeJS). If `observable_array` contains 10 HTTP requests, and each request takes 3 seconds to complete, no other requests can be made for 30 seconds.

What I'm looking for is a way to execute request 1, wait for the response from the server to complete, then execute request 2, then wait for the response, etc. Using this approach means that new requests don't have to wait 30 seconds before `observable_array` is complete to be executed by the server... They'll only wait a max of 3 seconds.

I came up with the following solution, but I'm sure someone more knowledgeable has a more elegant solution.

```
let observable_array = [observable1, observable2, ...];

var queue = function(t, ob) { // Needed to use var instead of let because of scoping...

  if (ob) {

    ob.subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Res: ', res);
      queue(t, observables.shift());
    }, err => {
      console.log('Err: ', err);
    });

  }

}

queue(this, observables.shift());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequential subscription to an array of observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388455/sequential-subscription-to-an-array-of-observables)

Comment: I'm not sure his problem is the same - the linked 'duplicate' does not care about the concurrent executions, which OP does care about - he only cares about subscribing to the results sequentially. The difference is caring about too many concurrent http requests...

Comment: you should rather look for a solution on your backend, because if someone want to overflow your callstack it's gonna be easy...

Comment: Just use `concat` instead of `forkJoin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your favorite flavour of flatMap/mergeMap and add a concurrent parameter. This will limit the number of concurrent observables/requests you're serving.

```
//emit value every 1s
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);

const example = source.mergeMap(
    //project
    val => Rx.Observable.interval(5000).take(2),
  //resultSelector
  (oVal, iVal, oIndex, iIndex) => [oIndex, oVal, iIndex, iVal],
  //concurrent
  2 
);
/*
        Output:
        [0, 0, 0, 0] <--1st inner observable
        [1, 1, 0, 0] <--2nd inner observable
        [0, 0, 1, 1] <--1st inner observable
        [1, 1, 1, 1] <--2nd inner observable
        [2, 2, 0, 0] <--3rd inner observable
        [3, 3, 0, 0] <--4th inner observable
*/
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Taken from https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Notice the 2 as the final parameter to limit the concurrent requests to a maximum of two. Obviously you could change this to 1. The example above emulates the observables with `.interval` - which you would just replace with your own observable list.